# Função de Probabilidade no R

Tags: r

Estou tentando rodar essa função probabilidade, mas o resultado não aparece no console, apenas o sinal de +, como se estivesse faltando algo, o que pode estar havendo?

```r
probab <- function(A, E) {
        resultado = (A / E)*100 
        print(resultado, digits = 3) 
}
probab(nrow(enem_campinas), nrow(enem2019_tratado))
```

Comment: Não vejo qualquer problema, se houver algum deve ser em linhas anteriores a essas.

Comment: Oi @Juliana Lanaro! O seu código parece bem escrito. O "+" no console indica que houve algúm parêntese que ficou aberto em algúm momento e que o R espera que seja escrito mais código. Pode ser o que @Rui Barradas sugere ou talvez você digitou no lugar errado ao momento de rodar o código. Você pode eliminar os objetos `rm(list = ls())` da sessão e depois rodar a função para conferir.

Comment: Apertar `ESC` duas vezes costuma resolver o problema.

Comment: Prezados, muito obrigada pelas sugestões, deixei de lado a última chave, ao rodar o código. Falta de atenção.